# Laravel 8 API how to check if user has valid token in controller without auth middleware in routes file?

Tags: php, authentication, jwt, laravel-8

How to check if user has valid token in controller without auth middleware in routes file? I try to do it this way in Basecontroller but it always return false:

```
protected function isAuthenticated()
{
    $isAuth = auth('api-web-app')->check();

    Log::info($isAuth);

    if( $isAuth ) {
        Log::info(auth('api-web-app')->check());
    }
    else {

        Log::info(auth('api-web-app')->check());
    }
}
```

There is api-web-app guard in auth.php config file

```
    'api-web-app' => [
        'driver' => 'jwt',
        'provider' => 'customers',
        'hash' => false,
    ],
```

so I expected it will run the same logic as auth middleware, but it seem it is not.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is how Laravel executest middlewares. They all runs after controller::__construct() method. I thought they already run. So if I called isAuthenticated() in constructor other middleware which I expected, did not run yet.